# Find all numericupdown in form visual basic

Tags: numeric

you can search on the form all the NumericUpDown and therefore report the value of all zero?

I would like to do something like a for loop that controls the form and see how many objects of that type are available, then if the user presses a key, all the NumericUpDown must return a value of 0 do not know if you can do this, I ask the 'help of you experts.

```
Dim count As Integer
    count = 0
    For i = 0 To Me.GroupBox1.Controls.Count - 1
        Dim name As String
        name = Me.GroupBox1.Controls(i).GetType().ToString()
        If name.Contains("NumericUpDown") Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next
    Label1.Text = count.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form has a Controls collection.   You can loop through that and check the type by calling GetType() [inherited from System.Object].   If you want to handle subtypes of NumericUpDown, you could try casting the control to NumericUpDown while catching the exception you will see if the control is not a NumericUpDown.

Your VB coding skills are probably better than mine.  Been a long time since I wrote VB.   Here's a rough example.  I put this code in a button click event.  You can pull the whole solution from my GitHub repository: https://github.com/kc1073/Samples

```
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0
    For i = 0 To Me.Controls.Count - 1
        Dim name As String
        name = Me.Controls(i).GetType().ToString()
        If name.Contains("NumericUpDown") Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next
    Label1.Text = count.ToString()
```

KC

Comment: Do not worry, I appreciate your help, I am also a bit 'rusty on vb. 
I comunqe the label returns 0, it is not because I entered the numeriupdown within groupbox? This could fallare somehow the research?

Comment: UPDATE: I tried it now, and actually can not find the NumericUpDown inside the groupbox but outside it. How can fix this?